# Inferring namespace of freestanding function

Tags: c++, namespaces

Question on namespace qualification: Why isn't the namespace of the function inferred below?

```cpp
namespace X {

void func(int) {}

struct Z{
   void func(){
      //func(int{}); does not compile
      X::func(int{}); // this works
   }
};

}

int main() {
   X::Z z;
   z.func();
}
```

Comment: It's not about the namespace; an unqualified name lookup finds `Z::func` and stops looking. Roughly speaking, an unqualified name lookup looks for the name in the current scope and then moves outward to search its enclosing scopes; it stops as soon as a declaration of that name is found. Even if the entity thus found is later discovered to not be usable in the original context. Another way to think about it: `Z::func` hides `X::func` within the scope of class `Z`, and so a qualified name is required to refer to `X::func`

Comment: If you give a different name to the member function of `Z`, you'll find that plain `func(0)` works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That sure looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, the key here appears to be the look up is based on just the name and not the entire signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This specific part of C++ can be [generally called "unqualified name lookup"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup). This term describes taking a single identifier in a C++ program and then determining which actual type, or object, or function, or class, it is referencing.

For example, there can be many things called `rosebud` in a C++ program, so

```
rosebud();
```

This can reference a class method of this name, and this calls it. Or this could be an object with an overloaded `()` operator, which invokes it. There could also be something called `rosebud()` in a different namespace. Unqualified name lookup specifies which one of these this particular `rosebud` references.

```
struct Z{
   void func(){
```

Here we're in a method of class `Z`. Unqualified name lookup first looks for identifiers that are members of this class. ***Only if it's not found*** then does unqualified name lookup looks in the global namespace, to see if something is there.

```
      func(int{}); // does not compile
```

Well, there happens to be a method with the name `func` in this class, so this `func`'s unqualified name lookup resolves to this method. This fails, because that `func` method takes no parameters.

Unqualified name lookup considers where exactly the unqualified identifier occurs. When it occurs in a class, unqualified name lookup searches the class's members, first.

Even though there's also a `func` function in the global scope, unqualified lookup finds the class method, and that's it (quoting from the cited link):

> [unqualified] name lookup examines the scopes as described below,
> until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the
> lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.

End of the road. The fact that there's also a `func` in the global namespace is immaterial. For unqualified name lookup, once "something" is found, it better work, or else.

These are just one of the rules of unqualified name lookup.

```
X::func(int{}); // this works
```

Well, yes. This explicitly references `func` in the `X` namespace. This symbol is (partially) qualified with an explicit namespace reference.